# Filemaker End Loop If Not Working

Tags: filemaker

So I am just trying to do simple scripting.

```
Loop
    Exit Loop If [$c = 100]
    Set Variable [$c; Value:1]
    Perform Script ["Import WS Keys 1X"]
    Set Variable [$c; Value:$c + 1]
End Loop
```

Why doesn't the loop end after 100 times?

Comment: I don't know what filemaker is but you have `Set Variable [$c; Value:1]` *inside* your loop. Wouldn't that reset `$c` back to `1` each time?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way instead:

```
Loop
  Set Variable [$c; Value:$c + 1]
  Exit Loop If [$c > 100]
  Perform Script ["Import WS Keys 1X"]
End Loop
```

What you have now alternates the value of $c from 1 to 2 and back:

```
Loop
    Exit Loop If [$c = 100]
    Set Variable [$c; Value:1]
    # THE VALUE OF $c IS 1
    Perform Script ["Import WS Keys 1X"]
    Set Variable [$c; Value:$c + 1]
    # THE VALUE OF $c IS 2
End Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 @michael.hor257k

if you want you loop to have one hundred iterations you should take the set variable statement outside of loop (to be exact the next code will give you 99 iterations):

```
Set Variable [$c; Value:1]
Loop
   Exit Loop If [$c = 100]
   Perform Script ["Import WS Keys 1X"]
   Set Variable [$c; Value:$c + 1]
End Loop
```

Comment: There is no need to "initialize" the variable: `Set Variable [$c; Value:$c + 1]` will set the value of the variable to 1 if it does not exist.

Comment: Of course! I just managed to misread your sample code. Indeed, you do not need to initialise the variable and your sample does the 100 loops as well.